# SimpleSamlPhp, Multiple Idps (Identity Providers), Multiple Sps (Service Providers)

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have been given a task at work to implement SAML 2.0. I have successfully set it up based on the docs.

However, I need to know if SimpleSAMLPhp can be configured as multiple idps per instance of SimpleSAMLPhp as an Idp and Multiple Sp's per instance as an Sp.

Answer (score 3):

You can [configure multiple SPs](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_1) per installation in `authsources.php`

> If you want mulitple Service Providers in the same site and installation, you can add more entries in the authsources.php configuration. If so remember to set the EntityID explicitly. Here is an example:

```
'sp1' => array(
    'saml:SP',
    'entityID' => 'https://sp1.example.org/',
 ),
 'sp2' => array(
   'saml:SP',
    'entityID' => 'https://sp2.example.org/',
 ),
```

You can [configure multiple IdPs per installation as well](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-reference-idp-hosted) however they need to be on different hostnames.

```
<?php
/* The index of the array is the entity ID of this IdP. */
$metadata['entity-id-1'] = array(
    'host' => 'idp.example.org',
    /* Configuration options for the first IdP. */
);
$metadata['entity-id-2'] = array(
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',
    /* Configuration options for the default IdP. */
);
```

Comment: Thanks for heads up , where im confused is does one need to create a new key and certficate per idp and sp and how to assign those dynamically based on a specific set of users

Comment: You can re-use keys and certificates. I don't understand what you mean by assigning them dynamically.